# How to parallelize a loop in Android?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, arraylist, android-asynctask

I have an evaluation algorithm, which is called by an AsyncTask. This is in an AsyncTask, because of updating the UI and it does in the background task nothing else than to execute the algorithm: `EvalAlgo.execute();`

The evaluation algorithm itself is a loop, which gets data from the database calculates a results and stores it in an ArrayList. 
The algorithm works later whith the results to get a final result. (Would be the task for the postexecution)

How can I parallelize the loop?

```
String sqlquery = "select sth from table";
resultset = statement.execute(sqlquery);
ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
while(resultset.next)
{

   arraylist.add(rs.getString("entry"));
   String anotherquery = "select something from anywhere where string = "+ rs.getString("entry");
   resultset2 = statment.execute(anotherquery);
   while(resultset2.next)
   {
       ....
   }

}
```

Comment: What do you understand by 'parallelize', or what do you want to parallelize?

Comment: I want to parallelize the while loop. There are more than one result and these results should be handled parallel, if it is possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get it. 'the result should be handled parallel'... what do you mean by 'handled'?

Comment: The while loop is executed several times (depending on the number of results from the database). That is meant.

Comment: I know that!! It's a loop! But what do you want to run in parallel?? Process two records at the same time?

Comment: Oh sorry, I see the misunderstanding now. In the while is another while loop, which handles a database query based on the previous result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48030/discussion-between-irgendw-pointer-and-merlevede)